# How to solve this separable differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is the equation:
$ y'\sin x + y\cos x = 0 $

condition $y(\pi/2)=4$

My solution:

$dy \sin x = -y\cos x dx $

$\int dy/y = \int \cos x/\sin x dx $

$u =\sin x ,~~ du =\cos x dx$

$ - \ln y = \ln u  $

$ - \ln y = \ln \sin x +\ln c  $

$-\ln y = \ln c \sin x $ , canceled $\ln$ from both sides

$ y = -c\sin x $

I solved it and got $y=-c\sin x$, $c=4$

The correct answer (according symbolab) should be $y = c/\sin x $

Is my answer correct ? If not, why ?

And a general question: Do I always have to isolate $y$ in a differential equation ?

Comment: If you show us how you reached that solution, we can tell where your made a mistake.

Comment: $-lny = ln(\frac{1}{y})$ so when you 'cancel ln from both sides' (in other words, exponentiate both sides) you end up with $\frac{1}{y}$ not $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake in after the line with the words, "canceled ln from both sides."  When you move the minus to the right side, it's outside the $\ln$, so when you move it inside, you get $1/\sin x.$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is incorrect
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(y\sin{(x)}\Big)=0$$
$$y\sin{(x)}=C$$
$$y=\frac{C}{\sin{(x)}}$$
The value of $C$ can then be found to be $4$ from the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well $$y=-c\sin x \to y'=-c\cos x$$
$$\to -c\cos x \sin x -c\cos x \sin x=-c\sin 2x \not\equiv 0$$

So your answer is not correct. Don't forget you can always substitute your answer to check if it is correct.

Instead, spot the product rule used here: $$y'z+yz'=(yz)'$$